# How to generate index column based on another column

Tags: sql, oracle

For example, if here is

```
  Student        Course
---------------------------
student 1   |     Math
--------------------------
student 1   |     English
--------------------------
student 1   |     Art
--------------------------
student 2   |     Math
--------------------------
student 2   |     Economics
--------------------------
student 3   |     Math
--------------------------
student 3   |     English
--------------------------
```

How I would like to generate the index column of courses based on student, like this

```
  Student        Course       Index
--------------------------------------------
student 1   |     Math      |   1
--------------------------------------------
student 1   |     English   |   2
--------------------------------------------
student 1   |     Art       |   3
--------------------------------------------
student 2   |     Math      |   1
--------------------------------------------
student 2   |     Economics |   2
--------------------------------------------
student 3   |     Math      |   1
--------------------------------------------
student 3   |     English   |   2
--------------------------------------------
```

So basically the 3rd column on the second table is the index/sequence of course per student, but I want the second table become a query to the second table (in Oracle), just cannot find a solution. I can only make the sum, but not the index.

Comment: Does the order of courses per student matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ROW_NUMBER()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) is what you are looking for

```
SELECT Student
       ,Course
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student ORDER BY Course DESC) AS "Index"
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Afaik you need to quote "Index" since it's a keyword.

Comment: True @JoachimIsaksson. Edited.

Comment: You woz robbed.  Even had a link to the docs. No justice. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the row_number window function.

```
select student, course, 
    Row_number() over (partition by student order by course) 
from the_table
```